# Twig Set array value based on key

Tags: html, symfony, twig

i found around here a similar question like this one but the answers from there didn't help me.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Permission</th>
{% for role in roles %}
    <th>{{role}}</th>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% for permission in permissions %}
    {% if permission.PermissionName != currPerm %}
        {% if currPerm != '' %}
        <tr>
            <td class="current-permission">{{currPerm}}</td>
            {% for perm in permArray %}
            <td>{{perm}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endif %}

        {% set currPerm = permission.PermissionName %}
        {% set permArray = default %}
    {% endif %}
    {% set permArray[permission.RoleId] = '&check;' %}
{% endfor %}

<tr>
    <td>{{currPerm}}</td>
    {% for perm in permArray %}
    <td>{{perm}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
</table>
```

The code above contains this line

```
{% set permArray[permission.RoleId] = '&check;' %}
```

Where i have problems setting the value for each key that it contains i tried with merge but with any luck it only adds a new key to the array and that's all.
If you have any other advices for this code i'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

With Twig you are not allowed to assign a value to an array key like this.

You must use the [merge filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html) to do something like :

```
{% set permArray[permission.RoleId] = permArray|merge({permission.RoleId:'&check;'}) %}
```